# iOS: scrollToRowAtIndexPath doesn't display correct top indexpath for last page

Tags: ios, uitableview, scrollview, nsindexpath

I am trying to scroll tableview programmatically as coded following. Please note that I have increased the content size so I can see few last few remaining rows. I can scroll manually correctly to get required indexpath at top but programmatically it's not happening.

```
[tableview reloadData];

CGSize size = tableview.contentSize;
size.height += 1000;
tableview.contentSize = size;

int rows = [tableview numberOfRowsInSection:0];
int numberofRowsInView = 17;
for (int i = 0; i < ceil((float)rows/numberofRowsInView); i++) {
    [tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i * numberofRowsInView inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
    ....
}
```

For total rows 60, I expect this code to return cell views of 0-16, 17-33, 34-50, 51-59 but for the last scroll it returns 43-59 i.e. full 17 rows view while based on above code, top indexpath should be 51 for the last page!

Can someone please help me to sort this out. Thanks.

This is manually scrolling image:

[image: Manually scrolling]

This is done programmatically:

[image: Programmatically scrolling]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I am not going to get this working. I need last page cells only for fraction of time and then I reset back to original tableview frame.

```
int rows = [tableview numberOfRowsInSection:0];
int numberofRowsInView = 17;

for (int i = 0; i < ceil((float)rows/numberofRowsInView); i++) {
    NSUInteger remainingCells = rows - i*numberofRowsInView;
    if(remainingCells < numberofRowsInView) {
        CGRect frame = tableview.frame;
        frame.size.height = remainingCells * tableview.rowHeight;
        tableview.frame = frame;
    }

    [tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i * numberofRowsInView inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
     ......

  }
```

Now it shows exactly remained cells on last page! I don't need to set contentSize anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If 17 rows fit on the screen then you can't scroll so that less than 17 items are shown. So, the table view will take the row that you have requested to be at the top and scroll to the nearest one that means the view is 'full' of rows. Basically it's because 60 isn't (exactly) divisible by 17 so the table view won't let you only show a half 'page'.

---

Alternatively, you can try using the scroll view method `setContentOffset:animated:` based on the frame of the cell you want at the top (`rectForRowAtIndexPath:`).

Comment: I see what you saying and I did try multiple times and somehow it's stopping with full of row view at last page. Is there anyway I can force it to go up by what index path I asked for? I can do it manually as I have set content size way more than actual rows!

Comment: Check if the content size is actually changed as the table view 'own's the content size and is probably changing it back. You could change the frame of the table view, but it may look a bit weird when you come to scroll. Why do you want a part last page displayed? Would turning on paging help (I haven't tried that in a table view...)

Comment: Yes it is actually changing content size. I can manually scroll to make 51st cell top most but programmatically it's not doing it. Please see attached images of my tableview - last page.

Comment: Thanks for your help Wain. I don't think there will be straight way to do this. I have posted my answer. May be the only way!